# Jquery Post Button

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a page in which multiple posts are coming from database and on these post one can comment 
when writing comment in text area i am doing some ajax call on POST button 
currently I am having only 5 posts in my home page 
Issue is POST button is working fine for only the first post i am seeing the Response text before parsing and after parsing but when i click on other post POST button my console doesnt show any thing heres my code

```
{'
$(document).ready(function()
{
//this will fire only when page is fully loaded
$('#comment-post-btn').each(function()
{
    $(this).click(function()
    {
 console.log("Button is working fine");
 comment_insert_btn_click();
  });
 });
 function comment_insert_btn_click()
 {
 var _comment=$('#comment-post-text').val();
 var _userId=$("#userId").val();
 var _userName=$("#userName").val();
 if(_comment.length > 0 && _userId!=null)
 {
 console.log(_comment + "UserId: " + _userId + "UserName: " + _userName);
 $.post("comment-insert.php" , 
    {
        task : "comment-insert",
        userId : _userId,
        comment: _comment
    },
        function(data)          
        {    
            console.log("ResponseTextBeforeParsing " + data);
            data = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log("ResponseTextAfterParsing " + data);

            comment_insert(data);
            console.log("ResponseTextAfterParsing " + data);

        }
    )
 $('.comment-insert-container').css('border' , ' 1px solid #fffff0');
 }
 else
 {
 $('.comment-insert-container').css('border' , ' 1px solid #ff0000');
 console.log("the text area was empty");
 }

$('#comment-post-text').val("");
}
'}
```

Comment: You can't use one id for multiple DOM elements. Change them to classes

Comment: Element id must be unique. Duplicates are not valid.

Comment: if i am getting you right then i can not use classes as the posts are coming from database and i need to enable this button to every post coming from database

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register the clicks with `.each()` and duplicate id are not valid. So you either devise a system to generate unique id or use the class attribute.

```
$(".comment-post-btn").on("click", function(e) {
    var me = $(this);  // the instance that triggered the click

});
```

Since it looks like you're trying to get form values, trap the form submission instead.

```
$("form.my-form-class").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var data = form.serialize();
    var comment = form.find("textarea[name='comment']").val();

    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: i have to do this in a single event  can you please tell me how can i use class attribute here ???

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean by single event?

Comment: how can i change the id of my post button dynamically so that it will work for every post coming from database and what i should put instead of #comment-post-btn in jquery where i have previously mention id of button

Comment: You replace `id` with `class`. `<button id="comment-post-btn">` is not valid because id is not unique (you have multiple buttons with this id). So change it to `<button class="comment-post-bnt">` now your selector is `$(".comment-post-btn").on("click", handler)`. This way all buttons are coded the same way but within the handler `$(this)` tells you which button instance triggered the event. How do you identity each post? Do you have a `postId`?

Comment: changing button id to classes worked :D 
i have changed `$(this)` and `(each)` function 
but new problem is in getting comment text as i am getting this like
 `var _comment=$('#comment-post-text').val();`
i need to get text from every text area in my screen